# In php, can parse_url and http_build_url be used to detect malformed urls and prevent xss attacks? Is there something better?

Tags: php, url, xss

I want to allow users of my site to post urls. These urls would then be rendered on the site in the href attributes of a tags. Basically, user A posts a url, my site displays it on the page as an  tag, then user B clicks it to see pictures of kittens.

I want to prevent javascript execution and xss attacks, and ensure there are no malformed urls in the output I generate.

Example: User A posts a malformed url, supposedly to pictures of kittens. My site tries to generate an  tag from user A's data, then user B clicks the resulting link. User A has actually posted a malformed url which adds a javascript "onclick" event in the  to send the victim's cookies to another site.

So I want to only allow correctly formed urls, and block out anything other than http/https protocols. Since I'm not allowing anything here which doesn't look like a url, and the user is not providing me html, it should be pretty simple to check by parsing and reforming the url.

My thinking is that parse_url should fail with an error on malformed urls, or it replaces illegal characters with '_'. I can check the separated parts of the url for allowed protocols as well. Then by constructing a url using http_build_url, I take the parts separated by parse_url and put them back together into a url which is known to be correctly formed. So by breaking them down this way first, I can give the user an error message when it fails instead of putting a sanitized broken url in my page.

The question is, will this prevent xss attacks from doing evil if a user clicks the link? Does the parsed and rebuilt url need further escaping? Is there a better way to do this? Shouldn't this be a solved problem by now with functions in the standard php libraries?

I really don't want to write a parser myself and I'm not going to even consider regular expressions.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you need to do is just escape content properly when building your html. this means that when a value has a `"` in it, you build your html with `&quot`;

Protecting against XSS isn't primarily about validating URL's it's about proper escaping. (although you probably want to be sure that it's a `http:` or `https:` link)

For a more detailed list of what to escape when building html strings (ie: the href attribute) see [HTML, URL and Javascript Escaping](http://jehiah.cz/a/guide-to-escape-sequences)

Answer (score 0):

No, `parse_url` is  **not** meant to be a URL validator.

You can use [`filter_var`](http://us.php.net/filter_var) for this:

```
filter_var($someURL, FILTER_VALIDATE_URL);
```

Answer (score 0):

So, in PHP, you would use something like:

```php
<?php

$userlink = "http://google.com";
$newlink = htmlentities($userlink);
$link = "<a href=\"$newlink\">$newlink</a>";

?>
```

Answer (score -3):

Depending on a few other things, you might just validate the URL by checking if it points to any content. Here is an example:

figure 1

```
<?php

// URL to test
// $url = "";

$content = file_get_contents($url);

if(!empty($content)){

echo "Success:<br /><iframe src=\"$url\" style=\"height:400px; width:400px; margin:0px auto;\"></iframe>";

}else{

echo "Failed: Nothing exists at this url.";

}

?>
```

Curl is another option. With cURL you can just return http headers then check the error code it returns. ie Error 404 = page not found, 200 = OK, 201 = Created, 202 = Accepted, etc etc

Good luck!

~John
http://iluvjohn.com/

Comment: Implementing this on a production website where you most likely would get $url as user input would pose a serious security threat, so don't do it.

Comment: This is a security threat. Never load the content of a URL provided by an user.